# \perp with two vertical lines

Tags: symbols

I searched on Detextify, but I cannot find the symbol

```
    | |
    | |
    | |
    | |
-----------
```

in LaTeX. There is `\perp` with only one vertical line. I look for a symbol which looks exactly like `\perp`, but has two vertical lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `$A\perp B \perp\kern-5pt\perp C$` should work, the value of 5pt being subject to aesthetic interpretation.  This question may be a duplicate, but I can't find the reference to it.

Comment: related: [A conditional independence symbol that looks good with \mid?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154530/579)  also [Is there a standard symbol for conditional independence?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3631/579)

Comment: related: [Is there a standard symbol for conditional independence?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/)

Comment: related: [Not independent Sign in Latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174118/16967). Also the non-negated independent sign is covered by this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174143/16967).

Comment: there’s `\Perp` in the `newtxmath` and `newtxmath` packages.  (but seems  not to be in the ostensible ‘parents’ `txfonts` and `pxfonts`.)

Comment: @Keba: My classifier gets it (now): http://write-math.com/view/?raw_data_id=2637

Comment: Thanks for all the comments (and sorry for the duplicate, was not easy to search for). Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

There *is* at least one font that has two variants of what you're asking for: `MdSymbol`. They're  `\upvDash`(= `\Vbar`) and a shorter one, `\upmodels`. See my answer to a  [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164338/looking-for-a-specific-symbol-used-in-set-theory-cant-find-on-detexify/164343#164343). `MnSymbol` has only the latter.

As you may not want to replace every math symbol with those from MdSymbol, you can look at the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) to learn how to use just a few symbols from a different font.